# DNS name resolution for Docker containers not working from Host

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, docker

I have several Docker containers running in `bridge` mode and would like to address them by container single label name from my Host. My Host is a Debian Linux System

```
$uname -a
Linux sv2 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My `daemon.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "bip": "10.20.0.1/24",
    "default-address-pools": [
        {
            "base": "10.20.0.0/16",
            "size": 24
        }
    ],
    "ipv6": true,
    "experimental": true,
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd00::/64",
    "ip6tables": true
}
```

Everything seems to be working perfectly. Each Container receives an IP from the address pool via DHCP:

[image: IP]

However, I cannot access the containers by the container single label name:

```
$ping mycontainer
ping: mycontainer: Name or service not known
```

Creating manual host name entries is not helpful, because the IP address of each container can change with every restart. Fixed IP assignment would be a workaround, but not a solution.

Does anyone have an idea for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think docker exposes its internal DNS server to the outside.

You can do something like the following (not tested, just an idea):

- create a container which exposes a port to the outside and forwards DNS requests to the internal docker DNS server.
- configure your host resolver to use this port for a stub-zone.